# Spoof Windows registry value for specific process

Tags: windows, registry, hook

So i have a windows registry entry, which I want to change its value if process X does a query. 
Im Talking about:
Myproc.exe doing a query from the registry -> return mydata
Notmyproc.exe doing a query from the registry -> return notmyprocdata
is that feasible?
I thought on doing a hook or creating a simple kernel driver doing that for me.

Comment: Im still interested into some kind of PoC on how to properly hook RegEnumValue to spoof the values which gets returned via that API. I planed to do a simple dll which gets injected into target exe and every call over that API gets through my hooked API and finally spoofs the returned values. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You should hook [RegEnumValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regenumvaluew) API.

Depending your programming language you use there is several libraries like [Microsoft Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) for C++ and Delphi and other free and commercial libraries.

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1644/Hide-String-value-from-Regedit-by-Hooking-the-RegE) there is an example of hooking RegEnumValue API.

Comment: Firstly thanks for that sample, but sadly it’s a bit old and I’m having problems porting it to x64 since the asm instructions are different. Do you know if there is another better sample for my approach?

Comment: @Johnny which assembly instructions do you mean ?

Comment: In the sample project you sent me „pushad“ & popad“ I read that it’s not the same on x64